# Is there a Rails like framework for SOA?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, soa

For traditional monolithic MVC applications, Rails is great! But it's a bit harder to operate smaller services into it's rather bulky design. Sinatra is great for smaller HTTP based services but I'm curious, is there a Rails like framework (having generators and other helpers) for service orientated architectures?

Comment: You mean like https://github.com/interagent/pliny?

Comment: According to DHH, this is going to be part of Rails 5. See his keynote from RailsConf 2015: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJVTM7mE1Cc

Answer (score 1):

Brandon Hilkert has been doing some posts about this topic. You can check them out [here](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/a-path-to-services-part-1-start-small/). There are also some books available on Amazon like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368). StichFix also created a [gem](http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/11/04/simple-rails-apis-with-stitches/) to somewhat assist in this.

Comment: Link-only answers are often better expressed as comments.